# What is a "small minority"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, nouns, adjectives

What is a "small minority"? I can see this being argued either way:

- 1% is a small minority because 1% is a small number.
- 49% is a small minority because, albeit a minority, it is only barely.

Comment: I would never call 49% a "small minority" because "small minority"  and "barely a minority" are not at all alike.

Comment: Your issue is interesting, but mainly based on personal opinions!

Comment: What you talking about Willis.

Comment: This is really straightforward. A small minority is a minority that is small. 49% is not a minority that is small. It is indeed so huge it's almost a majority.

Comment: Wait.  Did no one get my joke or was it not funny?  Discuss.

Comment: @RyeɃreḁd I just didn't get it. But I'm laughing at your follow-up.

Comment: @njboot - Gary Coleman quote... He was a small minority!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "small minority" would describe 1%.

A "bare minority" or "slim minority" would describe 49%.

Comment: -1 According to who(m)? References?

Answer (score 0):

A '**small minority**' is often used in the context of a matter to indicate political, vocal organization, and strength

A **vocal minority** expresses their POV -as opposed to the **silent majority** who do not express their opinions publicly